# Настройка и запуск GUI-шного приложения на устройстве без дисплея (Orange Pi)

Tags: linux, gui, gtk, display

Пытаюсь прикрутить на Orange Pi программу Audio-Recorder. Подкупила меня именно она, поскольку имеет строку задания условий для запуска и остановки записи, чего не нашел в других программах. Настроил и совместил со всем остальным, что необходимо для решения моей задачи у себя на компьютере. Теперь пытаюсь перенести все на Orange Pi. В итоге, при попытке импорта настроек посредством dconf, а так же ручного изменения оных при помощи gsettings, а так же при попытке запуска самого приложения, получаю:
импорт настроек: `dconf load /apps/audio-recorder/ < ~/Загрузки/backup`

```
Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
Usage: dconf loadDIR
Populate a subpath from stdin
```

Настройка посредством gsettings: `gsettings set org.gnome.audio-recorder timer-text 'start if sound 25% stop if 900 kb'`

```
(process:641):dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: 
Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Попытка запуска самого приложения: `audio-recorder --command start,hide`

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: Invalid command line argument. Cannot open dislplay:
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(audio-recorder:637): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Попробовал решить проблему с помощью `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
Старые проблемы сменились новыми:
при попытке внести изменения через gsettings, получаю:

```
(process:629): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: 
Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch 
--autolaunch=b399586fcb5e4e72bddf07655cd5900600 --binary-syntax 
--close stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

при попытке запуска приложения, получаю:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (audio-recorder:635): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: 
Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: Invalid command line argument. Cannot open display:
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: 
Could not connect: Connection refused
** (audio-recorder:635): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not open display: :0.0
```

Что посоветуете к решению?

Comment: `unset DISPLAY` попробуй

Comment: @senior, это возвращает нас к исходным ошибкам

Comment: не всегда. я запускаю под руотм гуишное приложение в том случае. если удален этот параметр, иначе не запускается.
либо нужно инсы запускать, указывать дисплей и номер

Comment: @senior, в смысле, я попробовал команду и убедился перед тем, как ответить)

Comment: Вам нужен виртуальный сервер `X`, из таковых как минимум есть `Xvfb`. Может быть качественнее посмотреть в код программы и оторвать ей GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот один из способов:
Устанавливаем виртуальный фрейм-буфер: `sudo apt-get install xvfb`.

Запускаем его:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 640x480x16 &
export DISPLAY=:1.0
<приложение с нужными параметрами>
```